# MVC4 Wrong date format

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, date-format

I'm using MVC4 to develop an intranet web app. When I try to create a new **person**, I have to choose a **start date**. I've implemented a datepicker with a jQuery script in order to do that. I had a problem with the culture and decimal numbers but fortunately, with help I managed to fix it. The accepted date format is the **yyyy/mm/dd** format but I want to make it **dd/mm/yyyy**. Is it possible? I tried to change the format, include the  tags, ... No effect.

The Create View :

```
@model BuSIMaterial.Models.Person
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Person</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            First name : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { maxlength = 50 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Last name : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { maxlength = 50 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            National number : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NumNat, new { maxlength = 11 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumNat)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Start date : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new {@class = "datepicker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            End date : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "datepicker" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Distance House - Work (km) : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HouseToWorkKilometers)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HouseToWorkKilometers)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Category : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Id_ProductPackageCategory", "Choose one ...")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id_ProductPackageCategory) <a href = "../ProductPackageCategory/Create">Add a new category?</a>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Upgrade? : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Upgrade)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Upgrade)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
}
```

jQuery picker and globalization culture :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                        changeMonth: true,
                       changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'

    });
});

$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) ||
                !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    Globalize.culture('fr-FR');
});

jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
    range: function (value, element, param) {
        //Use the Globalization plugin to parse the value        
        var val = $.global.parseFloat(value);
        return this.optional(element) || (
                    val >= param[0] && val <= param[1]);
    }
});
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might want to write this code in an editor template for `DateTime` type properties, and then just use `Html.EditorFor` instead of `Html.TextBoxFor` for those properties. This will keep your code DRY.

Answer (score 1):

You should add attribute for model property

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```